# Lost/Stolen Samsung S4 Mini blocked be tracked?

Tags: samsung, lost-phone, android-device-manager

recently lost samsung s4 mini, which had sim and phone blocked. Tried to remote lock it using Androis manager, but said device was offline. Does this mean that they can get at my data even though I put that lock on?

Comment: Can you give a few more details on what "that lock" is? Unless the device was encrypted, there are always ways to get to the data once one has obtained *physical* access to the device.

Answer (score 0):

If this is installed then you can locate it .Go to google.com/android/devicemanager and see if your phone is picked up. Outside of that, reporting it stolen to the carrier and police is your next bet if you didn't install any software with remote capabilities. For more derails you can also refer Samsung India site.